# How do I make the right paddle in a pong game work?

Tags: java, graphics, pong

I am making a pong game for my APCS class. This is the code for detecting collision for the left paddle.

```
    if ((getX() <= p.getX() + p.getWidth() + Math.abs(xSpeed))
            && (getY() >= p.getY() && getY() <= p.getY() + p.getHeight() || getY()
                    + getHeight() >= p.getY()
                    && getY() + getHeight() < p.getY() + p.getHeight())) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

And

```
    if (ball.didCollideLeft(leftPaddle) == true) {
        System.out.println("collison");
        if (ball.getX() <= leftPaddle.getX() + leftPaddle.getWidth()
                - Math.abs(ball.getXSpeed()))
            ball.setYSpeed(-ball.getYSpeed());

        else
            ball.setXSpeed(-ball.getXSpeed());

    }
```

Both these blocks are in separate classes and work just fine. How would you rework this to work with the right paddle? I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: The code may not have copied and pasted correctly into the box, but don't worry about that.

Comment: Just a note: you should format all code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` button in the question editor. You can also do so after you have submitted your question, as you have an `edit` button. Formatting code is important, as well as giving as much information as possible. An **important** missing piece is what you mean by "I'm having trouble with that". Please explain what trouble you're having, add pieces of code and errors if relevant. Do all this by editing your question.

Comment: In order to be a successful programmer, you have to pay **critical** attention to hundreds of details at the same time.  In order to ask a successful question on Stack Overflow, you have to pay **critical** attention to details.  "Don't worry about that" would be a good attitude to get rid of as soon as you can.